# execute() not returning any warnings

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

I have this code to run a stored procedure using JDBC against a Sybase DB:

```
CallableStatement stmt = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call mysproc(?,?,?) }");
// call setXXX for each input param
stmt.registerOutParameter("return", Types.INTEGER);
stmt.execute();

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
SQLWarning warn = stmt.getWarnings();
while (warn != null) {
   builder.append(warn.getMessage());
   warn = warn.getNextWarning();
}
```

The stored procedure gets executed, but no warnings are returned, even though the stored procedure calls PRINT, which I can see if I run it manually.

If I change `execute()` to `executeUpdate()` then I get the warnings, but what can happen is that the stored procedure also returns a `ResultSet`, in which case the call fails because of an unexpected result. Unfortunately there's no way of knowing upfront what the call will return, but at the same time I need to collect the number of updated rows AND the warnings.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `PRINT`s in your stored procedure are not warnings.

Comment: How do I get PRINT statements then? Btw with execute() those PRINT statements are returned as warnings.